# Error message - Uncaught Reference Error: firebase is not defined

Tags: database, firebase

Someone should assist me.
I'm getting this error message.

import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.4/firebase-app.js"; import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.4/firebase-analytics.js"; const firebaseConfig = {  }; const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

Comment: Give some more context to your problem, like a code sample, file structure, etc. apart from that i think the error is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.